# What are available next-gen formats?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, spree, lighthouse, image-formats

To increase the Performance score in Google LightHouse, I would need to **"Serve images in next-gen formats"**. So, what are the available formats for this (I know about `webp`, webp is not supported in all browsers, that's why I don't want to use this format.)?

And is there any way or gem available for converting `jpg, png` formats to next-gen formats in **Rails**?

Or in javascript, is there any convenient and robust way to handle "Serve images in next-gen formats"?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Use WebP, and fall back to jpg in browsers that do not support WebP, using the `<picture>` tag.

See [this guide on CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/) :

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/awesomeWebPImage.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" alt="Alt Text!">
</picture>
```

Also, [BPG](https://xooyoozoo.github.io/yolo-octo-bugfixes/#cologne-cathedral&jpg=s&bpg=s) kicks pretty much every other format's a** because it's basically the super-efficient x265 video codec, adapted for still images. But it requires a JS polyfill because it isn't supported by any browser.

Comment: On the sample page BPG was larger than WebP in about 50% of images I checked (to be fair all images were within about 1% so negligible difference in size) and the image quality was identical from what I could see. What are the benefits of BPG (i.e. if I compress further than in the examples would I start seeing gains / better performance on a like for like basis?). Obviously it isn't any use for production as JS decoding of images would be super slow but interesting as never heard of that format before.

Answer (score 1):

### So, what are the available formats for this?

Taken from [the web.dev article on next gen formats](https://web.dev/uses-webp-images/)

> **JPEG 2000**, **JPEG XR**, and **WebP** are image formats that have superior compression and quality characteristics compared to their older JPEG and PNG counterparts. Encoding your images in these formats rather than JPEG or PNG means that they will load faster and consume less cellular data.

As WebP has the [most browser compatibility (at 86%)](https://caniuse.com/webp) I would only bother with that (especially as Safari was the only reason to use [JPEG2000](https://caniuse.com/jpeg2000) and they are now starting to support WebP, [JPEGXR](https://caniuse.com/?search=jpegxr) is useful if you need high performance in IE....so basically not useful at all! hehe) and serve jpeg elsewhere.

### And is there any way or gem available for converting jpg, png formats to next-gen formats in Rails?

The [webp-ffi gem](https://github.com/le0pard/webp-ffi) seems to be popular for doing conversions to WebP in Ruby.

### Displaying images cross browser

You can either use the [`<picture>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) and let the browser decide which image to use, or....

#### Or in javascript?

You could use JavaScript to see if the browser supports WebP and swap out the URLs dynamically. I would only do this if you are lazy loading the images and are using JavaScript anyway.

```
var supportswebP = false;

supportsWebPFunction = function () {
    var WebP = new Image();
    WebP.onload = WebP.onerror = function () {
        if (WebP.height == 2) {
            supportswebP = true;
            // or call your function to change the URLs here etc.
        }
    };
    WebP.src = 'data:image/webp;base64,UklGRjoAAABXRUJQVlA4IC4AAACyAgCdASoCAAIALmk0mk0iIiIiIgBoSygABc6WWgAA/veff/0PP8bA//LwYAAA';
}

supportsWebPFunction();
```